# Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: postgresql, docker

Galera alguém já passou por esse erro?
Estou tentando rodar o postgres via docker mas imprime um erro.

```
sudo docker start database

Error response from daemon failed programming external connectivity on endpoint database (9dcb5288477f88c9ff1ed918beccf6fa2710bb052aca5a278788bd83be5ea80a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
Error: failed to start containers: database
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deverá ter outro serviço a correr na porta 5432, ou até uma outra instância do mesmo container.

Comment: Isso é Bug da versão do Docker, atualize para 19x que resolve.

Comment: Atualizar o Docker para a versão 19 não soluciona o problema. O jeito é mudar de porta.

Answer (score 1):

O endereço que você esta tentando direcionar a porta 5432 ja esta em uso por outra aplicação se estiver utilizando o docker-compose, utilize a tag

port:
- 5431:5432